# How call uithread from another thread infinite

Tags: android, multithreading

I have 2 thread, my second thread infinite work.

It has a setImage method, when the data come, thread call the setImage method.

I want to when the setImage changed (i can understand with if(getImage != null)), draw bitmap on mainthread.

But if i do like this, it will be block the mainthread :

```
while(true) {
 if(getImage != null)  {
 // draw Bitmap
}
}
```

how can i do this ? I want to when the data changed anytime, send an event from another thread to mainthread to draw bitmap ?

Comment: Why don;t you use asynctask? You have to call  runOnUiThread whenever you want to update your UI with new data http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: how can i call runOnUiThread from another class ?